# How to create index on tomcat log file using LogStash

Tags: tomcat, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4, logstash-grok

I'd like to have some daily analysis from tomcat log file such as how many errors and exceptions raised and categories of them etc. So that I choose ELK to do that and am new to the log indexing.

Here is my conf file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "\localhost.2016-01-09.log"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }
    geoip {
        source => "clientip"
    }
}
output {
    stdout {codec => "rubydebug"}
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]

    }
}
```

And here is some lines of the log file:

```
09-Jan-2016 18:30:38.722 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
09-Jan-2016 18:30:38.796 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing log4j from [C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.26\temp\0-contact-statecollab-ws-15.12-SNAPSHOT-unknown-20151230-1152\WEB-INF\log4j.properties]
09-Jan-2016 18:30:38.901 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
09-Jan-2016 18:30:54.271 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
09-Jan-2016 18:30:54.316 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing log4j from [C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.26\temp\1-ohsms-ws-15.10.16-SNAPSHOT-unknown-20151119-1832\WEB-INF\log4j.properties]
09-Jan-2016 18:30:54.361 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
09-Jan-2016 18:31:14.627 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
09-Jan-2016 18:31:14.628 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
09-Jan-2016 18:43:18.329 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
09-Jan-2016 18:43:18.369 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing log4j from [C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.26\temp\5-exports-service-15.12-SNAPSHOT-unknown-20160108-1712\WEB-INF\log4j.properties]
09-Jan-2016 18:43:18.405 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
09-Jan-2016 18:43:29.405 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exports-ws': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected gov.hhs.acf.ohs.hses.model.exports.service.ExportsService gov.hhs.acf.ohs.hses.services.exports.ExportsWebService.exportsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [gov.hhs.acf.ohs.hses.model.exports.service.ExportsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=exportsService)}
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gisDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [hses_service] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [hses_service].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactService' defined in class path resource [contactContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contactPgTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactPgTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [contactDaoPgContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contactPgSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactPgSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [contactDaoPgContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'gisDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gisDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [hses_service] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [hses_service].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'drsExportsService' defined in class path resource [drsExportsContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'drsExportTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'drsExportTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [drsExportsContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'drsExportSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'drsExportSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [drsExportsContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'gisDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gisDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [hses_service] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [hses_service].
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exports-ws': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected gov.hhs.acf.ohs.hhhh.model.exports.service.ExportsService gov.hhs.acf.ohs.hhhh.services.exports.ExportsWebService.exportsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [gov.hhs.acf.ohs.hhhh.model.exports.service.ExportsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=exportsService)}
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gisDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [hhhh_service] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [hhhh_service].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactService' defined in class path resource [contactContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contactPgTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactPgTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [contactDaoPgContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contactPgSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactPgSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [contactDaoPgContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'gisDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gisDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [hhhh_service] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [hhhh_service].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ccrRegistrantExportService' defined in class path resource [ccrRegistrantExportPgContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ccrRegistrantExportTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ccrRegistrantExportTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [ccrRegistrantExportPgContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ccrRegistrantExportSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ccrRegistrantExportSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [ccrRegistrantExportPgContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'gisDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gisDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [hhhh_service] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [hhhh_service].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'drsExportsService' defined in class path resource [drsExportsContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'drsExportTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'drsExportTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [drsExportsContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'drsExportSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'drsExportSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [drsExportsContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'gisDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gisDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [hhhh_service] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [hhhh_service].
```

When I ran a script: "logstash -f first-pipeline.conf", it said

> Logstash startup completed

But when I check indexes using following line:

> http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices

There were no such indexes created. Did I miss anything? I don't want to change any of the tomcat configs on the server and would like to get daily reports from the tomcat log files instead of running server

I switched to Ubuntu to play around it more and checked log of elastic search. It said:

```
[2016-02-10 12:15:32,496][INFO ][node                     ] [Archie Corrigan] version[2.2.0], pid[6365], build[8ff36d1/2016-01-27T13:32:39Z]
[2016-02-10 12:15:32,496][INFO ][node                     ] [Archie Corrigan] initializing ...
[2016-02-10 12:15:33,232][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Archie Corrigan] modules [lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-02-10 12:15:33,269][INFO ][env                      ] [Archie Corrigan] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/loop0)]], net usable_space [8.7gb], net total_space [16.9gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2016-02-10 12:15:33,269][INFO ][env                      ] [Archie Corrigan] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-02-10 12:15:35,932][INFO ][node                     ] [Archie Corrigan] initialized
[2016-02-10 12:15:35,932][INFO ][node                     ] [Archie Corrigan] starting ...
[2016-02-10 12:15:36,044][INFO ][transport                ] [Archie Corrigan] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-02-10 12:15:36,052][INFO ][discovery                ] [Archie Corrigan] elasticsearch/CNUHuSKySm6osx2heQAIqg
[2016-02-10 12:15:39,132][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Archie Corrigan] new_master {Archie Corrigan}{CNUHuSKySm6osx2heQAIqg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-02-10 12:15:39,173][INFO ][http                     ] [Archie Corrigan] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2016-02-10 12:15:39,173][INFO ][node                     ] [Archie Corrigan] started
[2016-02-10 12:15:39,362][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Archie Corrigan] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

Comment: Based on your config, your stdout log should contain a copy of all events being sent to elasticsearch; what's there?  Also, check the logstash error log and the elasticsearch cluster log for any informative messages.

Comment: Hi Alain, thank you for your respond. How should I check those logs you mentioned? BTW, it was okay when I ran it with apache-type log file that was provided in the tutorial on their website.So that, does it mean do I have to provide different pattern?

Comment: Normally, the logstash logs are in /var/log/logstash on your logstash host, and the elasticsearch logs are in /var/log/elasticsearch on your elasticsearch host.  You'll need to identify the problem before you can identity the solution.

Comment: Alain, I edited my question by adding a log of the elastic search. There was no file in "var\log\logstash"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had to provide sincedb_path property(sincedb_path => "\null") in a input -> file property. Because elastic search thought that this index was already created and no need to create it again. Otherwise, ES waits until new lines added to the log file.